# Why the table in select query doesn't update after an insert query express

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, express

I need help, I'm learning express and typescript, and when I render a view with the result of a select query after an insert query, the table of the select query doesn't update (the result of the query are the data before the insert query) but if I see the table in mysql workbench the table is updated with the last record added using the insert query

**router.ts**

```js
import express from "express";
import * as doctorServices from '../services/doctorServices'

const router = express.Router()

router.post('/', toNewDoctorEntry, (req:any, res:any)=>{

    const errors =validationResult(req)

    if (!errors.isEmpty()){
        doctorServices.getEntriesdb
        .then(function(result){res.render("doctors", {"doctorlist":result, errors:errors.array()})})
        console.log(errors.array())
        return
    } else {
        console.log(req.body)
        const name = req.body.nameInput;
        const lastname = req.body.lastnameInput;
        const Specialty = req.body.specialtyInput;
        const Consultory = req.body.consultoryInput
        const Email = req.body.emailInput
        
        const addedDoctorEntry = doctorServices.addEntrydb(name, lastname, Specialty, Consultory, Email)
        //This effectively adds a new doctor because I can see it in mysql workbench

        doctorServices.getEntriesdb.then(function(result){res.render("doctors", {"doctorlist":result, 'success':"success"})}) 
        //This is the problem, this show the doctors table without the last record added using the insert query 

    }
})

export default router
```

toNewDoctorEntry is the validation of the data using express-validator, doctors is the view to display the data in a table and a form to add a new doctor

**doctorServices.ts**

```js
import {query} from './db'

export const getEntriesdb = query(`SELECT name, lastname, specialty, consultory, email FROM doctors`,[])

export const addEntrydb = (name:string, lastname: string, Specialty: Specialty, Consultory: number, Email: string) =>{
    const result = query(
        "INSERT INTO doctors(name, lastname, specialty, consultory, email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",
        [name, lastname, Specialty, Consultory, Email]) 
    
    return "success"
}
```

**db.ts**

```js
import mysql from "mysql2"
import {config} from "../database/connect"

export async function query(sql:any,params:any) {
    const connection = mysql.createConnection(config)
    const results = await connection.promise().query(sql,params)
    return results[0]
}
```

So, the idea is that the render of the view using the select query shows the data of the table doctors updated with the data added using the insert query. Also, I accept suggestion to improve the query function in db.ts to avoid the use of .then() to get the results of the promise in the routes because i need to replicate this with a patients and appointments tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query in `getEntriesdb` is only ever executed once, when the module is first loaded.  Each reference to `getEntriesdb` afterward is just referencing the same result.

Just like `addEntrydb`, `getEntriesdb` should be a *function*:

```
export const getEntriesdb = () => query(`SELECT name, lastname, specialty, consultory, email FROM doctors`,[]);
```

Then you would *invoke* that function to execute the query:

```
doctorServices.getEntriesdb().then(...
```

---

**Edit:** You're also not *awaiting* the `addEntrydb` function.  `query()` is an asynchronous operation which returns a `Promise`.  Instead of assuming the operation will be successful and returning `"success"`, return the `Promise` itself and the consuming code can follow up success or failure as needed:

```
export const addEntrydb = (name:string, lastname: string, Specialty: Specialty, Consultory: number, Email: string) =>
    query(
      "INSERT INTO doctors(name, lastname, specialty, consultory, email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",
      [name, lastname, Specialty, Consultory, Email]);
```

(Just like `getEntriesdb` does.)

Then you can follow up that operation with `.then()` callbacks, just like you do with `getEntriesdb`:

```
doctorServices.addEntrydb(name, lastname, Specialty, Consultory, Email).then(function() {
  doctorServices.getEntriesdb.then(function(result){
    res.render("doctors", {"doctorlist":result, 'success':"success"});
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it is half resolved, it shows the correct table but just if I wait a few seconds and refresh the web page, maybe it is due to the async function or the way the queries works

Comment: @darc33: That seems to be because `addEntrydb` is asynchronous and isn't awaited, so it returns too early (and assumes success, but doesn't actually verify success).  I've updated the answer.  Any time you have an asynchronous operation, the functions which call it should also be asynchronous operations and should be awaited any time you need the result of that operation (either with `await` or with a callback like `.then()`).

Comment: I use a timeout before render again and works perfectly. Thank you so much

Comment: @darc33: I'd advise against using artificial timeouts to introduce delays for asynchronous operations.  Instead, embrace the structure of asynchronous operations and properly follow up on their results by awaiting them or using a callback to be invoked when they complete.  Artificial timeouts will *always* either be (1) too long and cause unnecessary delays or (2) too short and still fail for the same reason.  (Or, even worse, will "work fine on my machine" and then fail in production.)

Comment: I know but I still don't understand the async functions, promisses and callbacks, so later I'm gonna test with .then(), thank you so much for your help